# Procedure on how to install WU-NETA--025(A)

Tags: networking, wireless, usb

Just installed Xubuntu 14 and bought a *USB Wi-Fi Dongle* model **WU-NETA--025(A)**.
The CD includes Linux installer but how do I install it? I'm new to Linux. Thanks.

```
fdc@fdc-desktop:~/Desktop$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 04d9:1605 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
fdc@fdc-desktop:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: Can you add the result from `lsusb` with the adapter plugged in?  This one might be able to use the mt7601 module from porjo's github

Comment: what is 1susb? I have no idea.

Comment: Open a terminal window and enter `lsusb` it is a small L then susb and press enter.  Use the mouse or touchpad to highlight the results and right click, then select copy and paste it in an edit to your question

Comment: `lsusb` will list usb devices that are detected by Linux just as `lspci` will list pci devices and `lsmod` will show loaded kernel modules(drivers)

Comment: Hi Jeremy31 what next after lsusb? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This usually works for that chipset

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git 
cd mt7601/src
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

And it should work but after a kernel update the wireless might fail again, if that happens

```
cd mt7601/src
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

Comment: What Next after "This usually works for that chipset"? It installed a lot of things but still my wifi dongle not detected.

Comment: Try a reboot as you may have had another driver loaded

Comment: done rebooting but still no new hardware detected.

Comment: Open terminal and enter `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info`  Then copy the contents of the wireless-info.txt file and paste it at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL it gives you

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11855648/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11855662/

Comment: wireless-info.txt file, you pasted wireless-info with no extension

Comment: the only file new to my desktop here is this wireless-info only, where can I find this wireless-info.txt? thanks

Comment: try `chmod +x && ./wireless-info` and see if the wireless-info.txt file is created after the script runs

Comment: fdc@fdc-desktop:~/Desktop$ chmod +x && ./wireless-info
chmod: missing operand after ‘+x’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
fdc@fdc-desktop:~/Desktop$

Comment: chmod +x && ./wireless-info - Run this on Terminal?

Comment: `chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info` and the wireless-info.txt should be created when the ubuntu forums script is done

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11876848/    is this correct?

Comment: That was correct.  What happens when you `sudo modprobe -v mt7601Usta` in terminal?

Comment: fdc@fdc-desktop:~/Desktop$ sudo modprobe -v mt7601Usta
[sudo] password for fdc: 
modprobe: FATAL: Module mt7601Usta not found.
fdc@fdc-desktop:~/Desktop$

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/300665/jeremy31  what next?

Comment: Did you have any errors during the `make` command?

Comment: I have no idea about the errors,  im just following your instruction. Hehe. Instruct me what to do. Hehe thanks